# ExtJS 5 - Interactive Map

Tags: extjs5

Hi I am using ExtJS 5 framework to develop my application.

I have a requirement to create reports where I need to show a report using world map.

I have found fusionmap(interactive map) provided by FusionCharts that suits my requirement where user can interact with the map.

Is there any similar component available in ExtJS 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I really like the [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) library.
You can easily add a map to a ExtJS panel like so:

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});

var map = L.map(yourPanel.getEl().id)
    .addLayer(tiles)
    .setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Also read the quick start guide [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html).

And then just follow [the interactive map tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend leafletjs. Here is a nice tutorial for integrating it into an extjs application: http://www.sencha.com/blog/integrating-ext-js-with-3rd-party-libraries/